# SQL Server Execution Plan issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I've got 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T2] (
    [Id] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [F1] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [F2] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [F3] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_T2_F1_F2]
    ON [dbo].[T2]([F1] ASC, [F2] ASC);
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T3] (
    [Id] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [F1] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [F2] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [F3] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_T3_F1_F2]
    ON [dbo].[T3]([F1] ASC, [F2] ASC)
    INCLUDE([F3]);
```

And these are my execution plans

[image]

The question is why Query #2's execution plan is not `Index Seek (NonClustered)`, why the Query Optimizer chooses to scan clustered index on PK, instead of non-clustered index `{F1,F2}` ?

Update #1:

[image: Query #2 Stats]

Comment: You probably have 0 rows in those tables so it doesn't matter. Put a million rows in there and update your stats.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I have 100k rows in both tables

Comment: Well those arrows in your execution plans are very narrow - how many rows is SQL Server estimating?

Comment: Also `IX_T2_F1_F2` doesn't include `F3` so any index seek would be followed by some other operation (key lookup, clustered index seek) to get `F3` and SQL Server probably estimates it's faster to scan the clustered index than a seek + (key lookup/seek)

Comment: @ta.speot.is Yeah, i thought about it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT [F1],[F2],[F3] FROM [T2] WHERE ...` requires three columns, and `IX_T2_F1_F2` only contains two of them.

SQL Server is sometimes recalcitrant when it comes to covering indexes that don't cover all the columns it needs. To satisfy the query it has to use the covering index in conjunction with the clustered index, and (simplifying a bit) the more operations involved the higher the query cost.

It estimates that scanning one index (the clustered index) is cheaper than using two indexes and you get a plan with a clustered index scan.

[Here](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2013/06/12/sql-server-tipping-games-why-non-clustered-indexes-are-just-ignored/) is an article that discusses it further, and at what point SQL Server will use a covering index in conjunction with a clustered index.

Comment: I vaguely recall Brent Ozar had a better article about covering indexes and why they are sometimes ignored but I could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your statistics are not up-to-date. You can use query hint to force SQL Server to use your preferred index, like with(index(your_index_name)). I would suggest trying this query hint to check the performance of your index.